# Cannot log into Yahoo! Messenger

Tags: yahoo-messenger

I am using the Yahoo Messenger client.  The problem is that it will not log in until after I have been logged into windows for 5 minutes or so.  If I try and connect before 5 minutes, it just sits there spinning.

Yahoo! Messenger (8.1.0.421)
MyYahoo Module (8.0.0.1)

Does anyone have any ideas.  I don't really know where to start on resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a service starting up on windows that is interfering with the requirements of YahooIM. Is it literally "five minutes," or just several minutes?

Comment: I think its just about 5 minutes, sometimes longer than others, not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to surf the net at that time? Perhaps you are not connected to the network yet. Doesn't seem all that likely, but maybe if you are on wireless I could see it taking a while.

Comment: Good point. My wireless can take a minute or so to pickup sometimes too.

Comment: I am connected to the net, just can't log into yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

I know AIM does this, but not sure if Yahoo Messenger also started doing this. If you fail your sign on too many times per minute then you get locked out of your account for 5 minutes. It's a security feature called password spinning. Check and see if anything is trying to make a yahoo messenger connection during startup, and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

i used to have this problem with vista , but it sorted out withupdating yahoo masseneger.
try [Yahoo! Messenger 9.0.0.2162](http://www.filehippo.com/download_yahoo_messenger/)

it should solve problem if you are properly connected to internet.
otherwise use some alternatives like pidgin or trillian astra